# Regenerating the hyperlinks in google sheet using google appscript for offline use

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a folder on google drive which contains a google sheet with the list of documents and their links in it. In the same directory, there is another folder with the actual pdf documents listed in the google sheet.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to export this folder **My Test Folder** to my local hard drive. The spreadsheet can be exported to either `.pdf` or `.html`. But I want to regenerate the hyperlinks in the google sheet to "relative pathing" on local hard drive so that they are now pointed at the downloaded files after exporting and still works. So, basically, the hyperlinks in the picture below should be changed to the local files on the disk.

[image]

I have tried to regenerate the hyperlinks in google sheet to `<a href="file:///../Test Documents/Test1.pdf> Test1 </a>` using appscript but once it is exported in `.html` these show up as text instead of actual hyperlinks.

My question are, is it even possible to implement what I am trying to achieve with Google Appscript only?

If it is possible, could you point me in the right direction how I could implement such function?

Comment: To link, use hyperlink formula: `=hyperlink("file:///../Test Documents/Test1.pdf", "Test1")` But it still won't work due to security, as written in the  linked answers.